# SXA Storefront Emails

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sxa-storefront

I'm currently playing around with the sxa.storefront. 
Now I noticed I don't get emails. I'm using papercut to listen to the localhost:25 smtp - also testmails from exm Campaigns which you can send out are going through.
When placing an order /register a user there is no confirmation mail. Now I'm wondering if I misconfigured something - Or if there is something I have to configure. Also in the logfiles there is nothing indicating an error. 

I'm working with:
Sitecore.NET 9.0.1 (rev. 171219)
Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 (On-Premise)

Comment: Have you done `Email Configuration` for SXA? See this https://doc.sitecore.net/sxa%20storefront/build%20a%20storefront%20with%20sxa%20storefront/build%20a%20storefront%20with%20sxa%20storefront/the%20commerce%20control%20panel%20settings%20for%20sxa%20storefront

Comment: If this doesn't help and nobody else  replies here, you should contact Sitecore Support. SXA Storefront should be officially supported by Sitecore Support.

Comment: Could you perhaps try to upgrade to SXC Update 1? Also are you sure there are some emails send out? :)

Comment: Well - If I use Simple Send Mail Functionality from Sitecore it works, Forgot password also works. I can send mails for testing campaigns but I was wondering if there are out of the box mails send when ordering or creating an Account in the SXA. 
But actually it doesn't look like there are mails implemented there. 
So I continue the quest to send out pretty mails like the ones I can create in the EXM in campaigns .